# Arvore Binaria com 3 ponteiros tem tratamento especial?

Tags: c, árvore-binária

Estou montando um programa hospitalar e a ordem dos pacientes será por uma arvore binária, levando em consideração um grau de urgencia existente no struct paciente, como mostro abaixo. Minha dúvida é: Tem algum tratamento especial para 3 ponteiros? Pois quando executo o programa parece que ele não fica salvo no struct arvore quando tento mostrar a arvore em ordem ela está sempre vazia.

Structs de paciente e arvore:

```
typedef struct Paciente{
    char nome[50];
    char cpf[50];
    char sexo[20];
    char sintomas[500];
    int telefone;
    int idade;
    int codi;
    int urg;
    struct Paciente *prox;
}paciente;

typedef struct Arvore{
    struct Paciente *No;
    struct Arvore *Esq;
    struct Arvore *Dir;
}arvore;
```

Funções de adicionar e Mostrar a arvore:

```
void adicionar(arvore **Arv, paciente *pac){
    arvore *temp = NULL;
    if (*Arv == NULL){
        temp = (arvore*)malloc(sizeof(arvore));
        temp->Esq = NULL;
        temp->Dir = NULL;
        temp->No = pac;
        *Arv = temp;
    }
    else {
        if (pac->urg < ((*Arv)->No->urg)){
            adicionar(&((*Arv)->Esq), pac);
        }
        else{
            adicionar(&((*Arv)->Dir), pac);
        }
    }
}

// Em Ordem (Do menor pro maior)
void Mostrar(arvore *Arv){
    if(Arv != NULL){
        Mostrar(Arv->Esq);
        printf("Nome: %s\nCPF: %s\nSexo: %s\nIdade: %d\nTelefone: %d\nSintomas: %s\nUrgencia: %d\nCódigo: %d\n", Arv->No->nome, Arv->No->cpf, Arv->No->sexo, Arv->No->idade, Arv->No->telefone, Arv->No->sintomas, Arv->No->urg, Arv->No->codi);
        Mostrar(Arv->Dir);
    }
}
```

Na Main crio ela assim:

```
arvore *Arv = NULL;
```

Comment: Por que um paciente tem um paciente dentro dele? Isso não entra em conflito com a necessidade de se usar uma árvore?

Comment: Isso serve para uma lista encadeada de pacientes mas é para uma parte completamente diferente do código. Logicamente eu não encontrei nenhum erro mas ele ainda não mostra a arvore, então pensei que talvez 3 ponteiros tivessem um tratamento diferente.

Comment: Não, a quantidade de ponteiros não interfere em nada com a abstração. Como é a chamada de `adicionar`? O único problema que encontrei envolveria esquecer de passar o endereço da raiz e passar a raiz propriamente dita. Apesar de achar que você fez uma recursão esquisita na função `adicionar` (eu faria iterativo, mas aí seria eu programando), eu ainda não encontrei nada dentro dela.

Comment: adicionar(&Arv, aux); Onde aux é um struct paciente com as informações já preenchidas. Eu usei essa recursão pq é o unico jeito que sei fazer, olhei o psudocodigo no wiki de um arvore e adaptei. Não entendo o porque não salvar a arvore, eu não encontro nenhum erro para tal.

Comment: Esse `aux` é um paciente? Ou um ponteiro de um paciente cujo conteúdo fora alocado dinamicamente?

Comment: Tenho de concordar com o @JeffersonQuesado, que a sua recursão é um pouco estranha no minimo, e provavelmente mais complicada que o normal com coisas como `&((*Arv)->Esq)`. Ainda assim não vejo exatamente qual é o problema. Neste [pequeno teste](https://ideone.com/aaTuRH) que fiz pareceu me estar a funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Esse aux é um paciente, eu botei a função de adicionar diretamente na função que cadastra o paciente, então nem chega a passar na lista encadeada, é direto. Já que vocês comentaram que sabem fazer a mesma recursão de forma mais simples, poderiam demonstrar? Esse foi o melhor que pude fazer sozinho. Tentarei procurar o erro em outros lugares então. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Esse é o arquivo completo do programa, ve se talvez vocês consigam encontrar o erro que não deixa ele salvar na arvore: [link](https://gist.github.com/dfop02/661377142f2825abfb8fe00189820d6b)